# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getAllContacts is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to render some data onto my page, but I got the error "Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getAllContacts is not a function" and cannot seem to track down why. It says the error is from this line: "this.props.getAllContacts();". I have been googling for hours.

```
export default class List extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getAllContacts();
  }

  showContacts(contacts) {
    return contacts.map((render, index) => {
      return (
        <ul key={index} className="results-container">
          <li>{render.first_name}</li>
          <li>{render.last_name}</li>
          <li>{render.email}</li>
          <li>{render.phone_number}</li>
          <li>{render.status}</li>
        </ul>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    const contacts = this.props.getAllContacts;

    return (
      <div className="list">
        <br/>
        <h1>All Contacts</h1>
        {this.showContacts(contacts)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      contacts: [],
      result: {},
    };
  }

  getAllContacts() {
    fetch('/contacts')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then((results) => {
      this.setState({
        contacts: results.data,
      });
      console.log(this.state);
    })
    .catch(err => err);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="nav">
          <Nav />
        </div>
        <div className="props">
          {this.props.children}
          <List
            contacts={this.state.contacts}
            getAllContacts={this.getAllContacts.bind(this)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `this.props` has two properties (`contacts` and `getAllContacts`) - neither one is a function.  However the value of `this.props.getAllContacts` seems to come from calling `this.getAllContacts()`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using this.props.getAllContacts both as a function (in componentWillMount) and as a list of contacts (in render). I think you should probably just update the render method in List to use the list of contacts passed in from the parent component.

```
  render() {
    const contacts = this.props.contacts;
    return (
        <div className="list">
        <br/>
        <h1>All Contacts</h1>
        {this.showContacts(contacts)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```